# View import is not working in ASP.NET Core MVC web app

Tags: .net-core, view, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC web application with a `_ViewImport.cshtml` but in view product model I get an error.

Product Model class:

```
namespace IdentityApp.Models {
    public class Product {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(8, 2)")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`_ViewImport.cshtml`:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using System.Security.Claims
@using IdentityApp.Models
```

Index view in `Views/Home/Index.cshtml`:

```
@model IQueryable<Product>

<h4 class="bg-primary text-white text-center p-2">MVC - Level 1 - Anyone</h4>

<div class="text-center">
    <h6 class="p-2">The store contains @Model.Count() products.</h6>
</div>
```

Error is shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Is the `Product` class in your `Models` folder?

Comment: yes the Product model is in place

Comment: Could you share your product.cs class

Comment: I don't find anything unusual in your code, Maybe you can clean  and rebuild your project to try again.

Comment: product model is mentioned after edit @Manik

Comment: Tried around 8 times now think that its due to access right in organization policies what you say?

Comment: I tried to replicate it in my VS code and coudn't find any issues.

Comment: i add a file name _ViewImports.cshtml thats saved my 3 sec on every file and this solved my above problem.